# A sequence of functions $f_n : [0, 1] → R$ which converges uniformly to a discontinuous function $f(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

***Give an example or argue that such a request is impossible.***

I argued that such a request is impossible because by theorem of the continuity of the uniform limit, if $f_n$ converges uniformly then limit function $f(x)$ is continuous. However I was wrong and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Your conditions don’t state that the $f_n$ must be continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a request is possible. Take
$$f_n(x)=f(x)\qquad\forall x\in[0,1]\forall n\in\Bbb N$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more interesting example. Let
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 1/q, & x=p/q\text{ in lowest terms}, q\le n \\
0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$
Then $f_n\to f$ uniformly, where $f$ is what function?

Comment: Would the person(s) who downvoted like to put a comment explaining what's wrong or how I should improve this?